# Accompanying notes to higher key

Tags: voice

Are there slightly lower notes a vocalist can sing when the key in a song gets a little out of his/her vocal range? Of course, without the song losing something. Particularly at 5:39 until the end of the song posted below.

Answer (score 2):

To retain that effect of a climax - no. Of course other notes are available - the next lower harmony will sound in tune, but it's the original notes' relative position in the song that makes them sound like that. With a smaller tessitura (voice range), the better option is to change the key of the whole song, so that those top notes sound as good as they can for you. This may affect other parts of the song, as they will then be lower in pitch, thus not so effective for that part of the song. It's always a compromise in a song with a large range which doesn't quite match that of the vocalist. Or swap parts with someone who can reach.

Answer (score 0):

Well .. if you change the note then it's going to sound different of course (as Tim states), but you might be able to get the similar impact with a slightly lower note.

An example I use is during Led Zep's "rock 'n roll". I have an 'empty' spot in my vocal range at a highish C which is about where that song's vocal line resides. If I'm tired, my voice wobbles so sometimes I drop it down a bit- instead of singing the tune around notes C, A and G over the A chord, I sing the tune around A, G and E.
Effectively : instead of basing the tune around a minor third and the tonic, I base it around the tonic and a 7th. Drops it by 3 semitones which is easily enough. The impact is pretty similar and it leaves me enough "oomph" (whatever it is) in reserve to maybe go back to the minor 3rd later in the song.

I think the reason this still works ok is because the *sound* of my voice is still pretty similar, just a lower note. Purists will notice of course, but hey ho.

Also the song stops at the end of each round, and the vocal line is "lonely, lonely lonely lonely lonely time" starting on that same C note (bent up a bit). That first C can be tough and it'sjust voscals then, so I'm feeling quite 'exposed' so, strangely, to avoid my 'empty spot' I sing a higher D instead. Same impact - 'wrong' note according to the original, but works just fine. Again I think it's because the vocal sound is similar enough.

I noticed the very high note around 5:38 in that tune is a 4th over the 'key' of the song (lyrics ="believe in you" I think) so you could flatten that to a minor 3rd - or if you need to reduce it more a 2nd may work but either way you have to work it in with the context of the rest of that section's vocals so that it 'pokes out' in a similar way.

I think the key thing is to do something whcih has a similar sound to your voice, even if the notes aren't following the original.

A good example of this not working is if you were to go into Falsetto (depending on your Falsetto voice- see later). At the top end of the chest or head voice, the sound is usually a touch gravelly and quite powerful. Replace that same note or a note above with a smooth, easy Falsetto and suddenly the impact is lost, even though you might be singing the right notes.

This depends on what kind of Falsetto you have of course - some people can do this change from one voice to another brilliantly, but some go from sounding like a rock god to a choir boy, which would lose the impact in that context.

Cool tune by the way :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a high note is thematic - the melody HAS to go that way or it would be a different song.  Sometimes it's a gesture - "look at me ending on a high note"!  But there's no moral principle here, it's just a song!  Will your version sound like a cop-out?  In that case, practice singing higher, take the whole song lower or choose a different song that you CAN sing.